# Is there a way to create a CheckBox without a label?

Tags: tables, hyperref, labels, forms, textfield

I am using Hyperref and Form to create a CheckBox, but I don't want any text near it. It should be without any labels, but I can't leave the parentheses empty, like so:

```
\CheckBox[checked=true]{}
```

I need a simple lonely box to check. I've already tried writing `\null` within the curly brackets but that didn't work and now I can't think of any other ways to do this.

---

**Edit**:
As an example: I want to create this table, where the 3rd column (with the square brackets) is where the checkbox should be.

The user should be able to check either one of them.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Q1) What is the meaning of Life?}\\
\hline \hline
a)& 42& \CheckBox[bordercolor=,checked=false]{}\\
\hline
b)& Make ur own& \CheckBox[bordercolor=,checked=false]{}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What I have noticed is that if leave the curly brackets in `\CheckBox[...]{}` empty, the program runs without error, but the resulting document doesn't show any interactive checkboxes.

Comment: yes there is. But please provide a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test a solution.

Comment: I don't have the [working] code, but I've shared what I want exactly through a picture.

Comment: you should not provide working code, but something that can be used as skeleton. I don't want to have to type all the \documentclass etc myself.

Comment: I can not confirm the claim "but I can't leave the parentheses empty". You might however, want to add a name, as for example in `\CheckBox[name=ch1, checked=true]{}`.

Comment: @leandriis 's suggestion worked for me! Thank you. Also, should/may I answer the question using your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a unique `name` to each `\CheckBox` resuts in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Q1) What is the meaning of Life?}\\
\hline \hline
a)& 42& \CheckBox[bordercolor=,checked=false, name=a]{}\\
\hline
b)& Make ur own& \CheckBox[bordercolor=,checked=false, name=b]{}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```